# How to send Font via Bluetooth to Zebra printer (Zebra imz320) via iOS SDK

Tags: ios, printing, zebra-printers

I must send some Font files to my printer Zebra iMZ320 via bluetooth. Im using Zebra iOS SDK, but can't find any way to send and store it on printer. I could do it manually by Label Vista but It must be done in 200+ printers.

Anyone have any suggestion or know what method from the SDK I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use CISDFCRC16 command to write font files to the printer. We are using CPCL as the printer language . So we use font file with .cpf extension. If we are using zpl as the printer language we can use .fnt or .ttf format font files.